# warning in ReactJS. A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled. This is likely caused by the value changing from undefined to

Tags: javascript, reactjs

- I'm learning ReactJS and try to make simple unit converter (from
  react's official site) meter to km
- This code is worked and doesn't give me any error but give warning in browser('s console)
- I just want to get rid of this warning

warning is:

> index.js:1 Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input to
> be controlled. This is likely caused by the value changing from
> undefined to a defined value, which should not happen. Decide between
> using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of
> the component. More info:
> https://reactjs.org/link/controlled-components

> ```
> at input 
> at fieldset
> at div
> at LengthInput (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:566:5)
> at div
> at LengthCalculator (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:609:5)
> at Lenght (this is my file name)
> at App
> ```

code is as follow:

```
import React from "react";

function toKilometer(meter) {
  return meter / 1000;
}

function toMeter(kilometer) {
  return kilometer * 1000;
}

function tryConvert(length, convert) {
  const input = parseFloat(length);
  if (Number.isNaN(input)) {
    return;
  }
  const output = convert(input);
  const rounded = Math.round(output * 1000) / 1000;
  return rounded.toString();
}

const scaleNames = {
  m: "Meter",
  k: "Kilometer",
};

class LengthInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.props.onLengthChange(e.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    const length = this.props.length;
    const scale = this.props.scale;
    return (
      <div>
        <fieldset>
          <legend>{scaleNames[scale]}</legend>
          <input value={length} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </fieldset>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class LengthCalculator extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { length: "", scale: "m" };
    this.handleMeterChange = this.handleMeterChange.bind(this);
    this.handleKilometerChange = this.handleKilometerChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleMeterChange(length) {
    this.setState({ scale: "m", length });
  }

  handleKilometerChange(length) {
    this.setState({ scale: "k", length });
  }

  render() {
    const scale = this.state.scale;
    const length = this.state.length;
    const meter = scale === "k" ? tryConvert(length, toMeter) : length;
    const kilometer = scale === "m" ? tryConvert(length, toKilometer) : length;

    return (
      <>
        <div className="container">
          <LengthInput
            scale="m"
            length={meter}
            onLengthChange={this.handleMeterChange}
          />
          <LengthInput
            scale="k"
            length={kilometer}
            onLengthChange={this.handleKilometerChange}
          />
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default function Lenght() {
  return <LengthCalculator />;
}
```

I have read some related answer on stackoverflow, most of the says that "we have to state the initialize value in `this.state` "
but i does this in `LengthCalculator`

Answer (score 0):

i think it is in the tryConvert if the length is a empty string it returns undefined and you get that warning if a value is undefined but has a onChange:

```
function tryConvert(length, convert) {
  const input = parseFloat(length);
  if (Number.isNaN(input)) {
    return; // this line returns undefined
  }
  const output = convert(input);
  const rounded = Math.round(output * 1000) / 1000;
  return rounded.toString();
}
```

To get rid of the warning you could make the value length or if no defined set it as empty string:

```
    <fieldset>
      <legend>{scaleNames[scale]}</legend>
      <input value={length || ''} onChange={this.handleChange} />
    </fieldset>
```

Comment: Yes, It's work... and if i do `return ""` then it works too. thaks